# Error when displaying data from Firebase in Ionic 3 mobile application - Error: TypeError: this.db.object(...).subscribe is not a function

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angularfire

I'm trying to create a simple chat application with Ionic 3 and Firebase. Registering and logging in users work. When they send a message, their message and username is saved in Firebase, but I can't show this message in my application:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.db.object(...).subscribe is not a function

I'm just trying to show the message on the console at the moment. Chat.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {

  username: string= '';
  message: string= '';
  s;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        this.username= val;
      }
    });

    this.s= this.db.object('/chat').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      username: this.username,
      message: this.message
    }).then( () => {

    }).catch( () => {

    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let username= '';

    this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {
      if (val != null) {
        username= val;
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage', username);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I set up Firebase in app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/register/register';
import { LoggedinPage } from '../pages/loggedin/loggedin';
import { ChatPage } from '../pages/chat/chat';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

export const firebaseAuth= {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCKjJFl1LvnViPdoGSuh2j85osPnevoM3Q",
    authDomain: "chat-97a37.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://chat-97a37.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "chat-97a37",
    storageBucket: "chat-97a37.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "197759314650"
  };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    RegisterPage,
    LoggedinPage,
    ChatPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseAuth),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    RegisterPage,
    LoggedinPage,
    ChatPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```